# How can I use bookmarklets in IE11 that involve cross-site scripting?

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript, bookmarklet, xss

I'm trying to use some bookmarklets that involve loading javascript from a trusted website.  In particular, [OpenSpritz](https://gun.io/blog/openspritz-a-free-speed-reading-bookmarklet/) and [Squirt](http://www.squirt.io/install.html)

I have *Squirt* working in Chrome, but I use IE11 for the most part.  When I click the bookmarklet, nothing happens.  I have tried other bookmarklets that are self-contained and they work.  The problematic bookmarklets are trying to load javascript from a third-party site, also known as cross-site scripting.

How can I configure IE11 to run trusted scripts from a third-party site or even from my local hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following registry setting to open files from a local hard drive:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/FeatureControl/FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN
```

Set the following name:

```
iexplore.exe
```

to this value:

```
00000000
```

then restart the machine.

**References**

- [IE Feature Controls: Local Machine Lockdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330732#local_mach_lock)
- [URL Security Zones Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537023)
- [Enhanced Protected Mode and Local Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/20/loading-local-files-in-enhanced-protected-mode-in-internet-explorer-10.aspx)
- [Understanding Local Machine Zone Lockdown](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx)
- [Tricks with Mark of the Web: Behaviors, XML files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/09/02/460120.aspx)